# Where is hive 0.11.0 metastore initialization script for mysql?

Tags: mysql, hive

I am trying to install the metastore in mysql. When I looked at the source code, there are many sql scripts but they are all upgrades. Which /where is the start-from-scratch DDL for the metastore?

The cloudera docs have this info (for version 0.10.0):

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE metastore;
mysql> USE metastore;
mysql> SOURCE /usr/lib/hive/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-0.10.0.mysql.sql;
```

But I do not see anything for version 11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is :  The version 0.10.0 "upgrade" script (as shown in OP) is actually the correct one to invoke . Although the name is "upgrade" it is used to create the initial schema.